# Change a UIButton's image that was created programmatically within a for loop Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I created a UIButton within a for-loop because the number of these button depend on a certain number in the database. However, I have to change the image of this button after it is clicked, which doesn't work.

What I have done is I tried holding an array of those buttons and trying to access the buttons like that, which I don't think is not working.

```
let buttonArray: [UIButton] = [UIButton]()

...extra code

for (index, num) in numberOfButtonsNeeded.enumerated() {
   let button = UIButton()
    button.tag = index
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tap(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    buttonArray.append(button)

}
... 

@objc func tap(sender: UIButton) {
   DispatchQueue.main.asnyc{
   buttonArray[sender.tag].setImage(UIImage(named:"Somename"))
 }
}
```

I can access the tap gesture but this button's image won't be reset. Is there a way I can access the button? I do not think this array works.

Comment: Define your terms. What is numberOfButtonsNeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is suspect:

```
 @objc func tap(sender: UIButton) {
     DispatchQueue.main.asnyc{
     buttonArray[sender.tag].setImage(UIImage(named:"Somename"))
 }
```

You are already on the main queue, and the sender is the button that was tapped. So you don't need the array.

```
@objc func tap(sender: UIButton) {
     sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Somename"))
}
```